# Typescript - Ionic 2 - MapSubscriber error, unhelpful error data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Hello all who read this.
I am working on an Ionic2 app where the user will send the server some image data, and if the server receives that data then I display a confirmation, but if there are errors than I displaying that there have been errors.

The issue is that when sending the image data Ionic/Typescript tells me there has been an error, but when checking the server the image data is received in its entirety, and the image displays just fine.

However, it is still very important for me to know via the client that the information has been properly received so that I can display it to the user.

The relevant section of code:

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    this.http.get(url).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log('InvoiceHttp.send() success!');
        resolve(data);
    }, err=>{
        console.log('Http error on InvoiceHttp.send()');
        console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Now when I run this function I get the console log message and the error output, but the error output is this:

```
ERROR: {"line":78889,"column":39,"sourceURL":"file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/601C2294-78EA-48A2-9BAC-B53C04ADD458/MyApp.app/www/build/main.js"}
```

which if I look at this line it takes me to the MapSubscriber definition, which leads me to believe this is an error with .subscribe().

My first thought was that maybe the servers response was not in a proper JSON format, but after changing the response to be both blank and {} the error still stands and I'm all out of ideas as to what could be throwing this error.

Thank you for any replies.

Comment: Just one aside question: why not to use `toPromise` operator? E.g. `this.http.get(url).map(r=>r.json()).toPromise().catch(err=>log(err))`?

Comment: Short answer: I didn't know about it but have since changed it.  It did give me a little bit more of a verbose response, but nothing that really helps me debug this.

Comment: Can you provide this updated response?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to not call json() on resp.
Map was getting mad that I was attempting to convert an empty response into JSON apparently.